# SQL server ER diagram relations

Tags: sql-server

I am generating an **ER Diagram** by **SQL Server**, but the relationships between the entities are not pointing to the columns they are supposed to (just to the entities).

Is there an option that would connect the exact columns the foreign keys should point to or should I do it manually every time?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the diagrams in SSMS are able to do this.  You will need to look at other tools to generate your required design such as Visio.

Comment: @hollow  It is overhead in the application and sensibly designed databases simply don't need it.  When you have `ContactID` in your `Contact` table and `ContactRef` in your `Sales` table, you don't really need that relationship line pointing the relevant field out for you...